# AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete_message'

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am writing a bot for Discord in Python(`discordbot.py 0.2.3a3`).

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content == "qwe":
        await bot.delete_message(msg)
```

When I write a command to delete a message, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete_message'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content == "qwe":
        await msg.delete()
```

And see if this works?